# How to redirect user to other link only when complete url matches

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-group

I want to redirect the user to other link only if the complete url matches and also is it possible that after redirection the url remains same as that of the old one from where user is redirected

I am writing the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://bestcenters.net/services$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://4677--586.rocketquotes.com/franchise [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What are example URLs you want to redirect and what is destination?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have solved the issue. You just have to 301 redirect the new rule will looks like this

```
Redirect 301 ^/old-page.html$ http://newdomain/
```

This is the rule that helped me achieve what I wanted.